# GDB debugging error -- "localhost:3333: Operation timed out"

Tags: gdb, embedded, eclipse-cdt, esp32

I just finished setting an Espressif project in Eclipse but upon debugging using OpenOCD after following the [instructions here](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/jtag-debugging/using-debugger.html#jtag-debugging-using-debugger-eclipse), I'm getting the following error:

```
Error in final launch sequence:

Failed to execute MI command:
-target-select remote localhost:3333

Error message from debugger back end:
localhost:3333: Operation timed out.
Failed to execute MI command:
-target-select remote localhost:3333

Error message from debugger back end:
localhost:3333: Operation timed out.
localhost:3333: Operation timed out.
```

Does that mean port 3333 is either busy or doesn't exist?
Also, when I ran `netstat` in terminal, I didn't see a port with `3333`. Could that be why?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities to get this error: openocd is not runing or it is busy.

you will see 3333 with netstat only if there is already a connection between openocd and gdb.

Since you dont see 3333 when runing netstat, most likely openocd did not start or it crashed.

run `ps ax | grep openocd` to make sure there is an openocd running.